# What's the relationship between PartialFunction and Function1

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala, and find from scala doc the definition of *PartialFunction* and *Function1*, as shown below:

```
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B
trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef
```

Q1) My 1st question is: what's the type of *(A) => B*?

And, I know we can turn the *PartialFunction* to be a normal function by the *lift* method.

But Q2) what's the relationship between *ParitialFunction* and *Function1*?

It seems if some function parameter is of type *Function1*, we can pass a matching *PartitionFunction* to it, as shown below:

```
scala> val process = (f: Function1[String, Int]) => f("1024")
process: (String => Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> val pattern = "([0-9]+)".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([0-9]+)

scala> val str2int: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
     | case pattern(num) => num.toInt
     | }
str2int: PartialFunction[String,Int] = <function1>

scala> accept(str2int)
res67: Int = 1024
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A ⇒ B` is syntax sugar for `Function1[A, B]`. Similarly, `(A1, A2) ⇒ R` is actually `Function2[A1, A2, R]`, etc. all the way to 22 (completely arbitrary limit). The definition of `PartialFunction` is thus

```
trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends Function1[A, B]
```

Since a `PartialFunction[A, B]` is also a `Function1[A, B]`, you can pass it into something that wants an `A ⇒ B`. The only reason we use `⇒` over `FunctionN` is aesthetic: it looks nicer. Indeed, since `⇒` isn't really a type name, we can't say something like:

```
type ApIntInt[T[_, _]] = T[Int, Int]
// ApIntInt[⇒] // Error: ⇒ is not a type and was not expected here
ApIntInt[Function1] // Fine: Function1 is a type, it has the right kind, so it works.
// ApIntInt[Function1] = Function1[Int, Int] = Int ⇒ Int
```

Since you're a beginner, you won't see this kind of stuff (higher kinds) for a long time yet, but it *is* there, and you may well hit it someday.

When you use a `PartialFunction` as a `Function1`, if you pass a value at which it is not defined, it (probably) throws an exception, which is usually a `MatchError` (but doesn't have to be). By contrast, if you call `pf.lift`, that creates a `Function[In, Option[Out]]`, which returns `Some(result)` if the `PartialFunction` is defined at a point, and returns `None` if it isn't, per the Scaladoc.

Ex:

```
lazy val factorial: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case num if num > 1 => num * factorial(num - 1)
  case 1 => 1
}
assert(!factorial.isDefinedAt(0))
factorial.apply(0) // Using a PF as a Function1 on an undefined point breaks (here with MatchError)
factorial.lift.apply(0) // This just returns None, because it checks isDefinedAt first
```